# Site Module 1.3.1 breaks STK compatibility

Tags: magnolia

I'm working in a magnolia project that I am trying to move from 5.7 to 6.2.
It uses the old STK templating and we would like to keep it as the effort moving to MTK could be really big.

When moving from magnolia 6.1.5 to 6.1.6 our templates are not showing anymore. I have noticed that the site module was updated from 1.2.4 to 1.3.1. In there some legacy methods related to themes where removed. See this [commit](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/projects/MODULES/repos/site/commits/bdbb2e01851ed19b7625e60d7f22baa47c2e826f#magnolia-site/src/main/java/info/magnolia/module/site/SiteModule.java)

This change brakes the STK for working to some extend as in STKTemplatingFunctions.java they are used.

```
// TODO dlipp/had: is that a good place to keep that code - you might have
// to access it from non-template related code. Maybe we shouldn't
// completely drop STKUtil but
// keep it for common stuff.
public Theme theme(Site site) {
    final String theme = site.getTheme().getName();
    return StringUtils.isBlank(theme) ? new ThemeImpl(new STKImagingSupport()) : (Theme) moduleProvider.get().getTheme(theme);
}

public info.magnolia.module.site.theme.Theme theme(info.magnolia.module.site.Site site) {
    final String theme = site.getTheme().getName();
    return StringUtils.isBlank(theme) ? new ConfiguredTheme(null) : moduleProvider.get().getTheme(theme);
}
```

Basically, moduleProvider.get().getTheme(theme) does not exist anymore.

I cannot find anything in the documentations that provides a workaround. Also I don't see any advice saying that the STK would not be usable anymore from some 6.X version.

I have found that the imaging modules was also affected by this change [here](https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/MTE-114?jql=project%20%3D%20MTE%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%201.5)

Has anyone faced also this issue? is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you expand your question to include the code that is actually failing due to removal of those deprecated methods you reference?

Comment: Added the code failing in STKTemplatingFunctions.java.
We still use the stkfn. Therefore we use STKPage and STKPageModel

Comment: @jan I have a more simple question that is not clear at all in the Magnolia documentation. Is it possible at all to use the STK with magnolia 6?
The last clue about it is here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/How+to+create+a+custom+webapp+with+STK+modules
Saying it is not possible to be use with 5.7 but we got it working.

Comment: STK (originally written for 4.0) relied on quite a lot of code that was deprecated throughout the later releases and finally removed as of 6.0. Rewrite of STK would be quite an effort and usage of it fell with the advent of headless. That was the main reason for decision to abandon the STK and just maintain it for most of for 5.x series but not any longer. That is also the reason for documentation saying that it doesn't work. Of course nothing is black and white and parts of the code relying on methods still in the code would be still working hence allowing use for smaller projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked magnolia directly and they confirm that STK is not expected to work in version 6.

https://jira.magnolia-cms.com/browse/SUPPORT-16220

The documentation is a bit confusing and for some reason they do not clearly say from which version STK won't work anymore.

We were able to make it work up to version 6.1.8 but it is not worth to keep it working with workarounds as any magnolia or module update could brake it again.